# how to load a file with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to load a file that I was created by php function but my code dont work

When I print 'chemin' it give me this location file as : `c:/wamp/www/test/fichier.html`

i want to call file fichier.html and show the result of its code in div result

I try to explode it to keep only `fichier.html`  but I can't please help me

```
<div id="result">            
    <?php        
        if(isset($_GET["chemin"])){
        $chemin = $_GET["chemin"];

        $fich=fopen($chemin,"r");
        $content=fgets($fich);
        $data_table = explode("/",$content);
        for($i=0;$i<sizeOf($data_table);$i++){
            echo $data_table[$i];        
        }
        }     
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: How do You know Your code doesn't work? Does it result in some PHP error message? Note that `fgets()` reads only the first line of the file, isn't Your pirst line empty? BTW You should also `close()` the file, when You are finished.

Comment: the content of the file is code html , i want open this file in a div and show the result of this code but the problem in the path, php dont show error but in the div there's nothing appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use explode.Just use [basename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
<?php
echo basename("c:/wamp/www/test/fichier.html").PHP_EOL;
?>
```

**Output:**

> fichier.html

**[WORKING DEMO](http://codepad.org/jW9FYo6p)**

Comment: i see , but in fichier.html there's a code html , i want to show it in the div not the path of file u see !

Comment: i use js now to resolve the problem and basename also , thank you a lot :)